# Tap on dropdown indicator in mobile theme doesn't get registered

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web

The area where the number of messages in the inbox/the dropdown for previous messages gets shown does not get activated upon tapping, tap a little bit further down and the tap is registered for "Ask" link.

I can see this behavior on Stack Overflow, Super User, Meta Super user but curiously not on Meta Stack Overflow. I use an Android device, the Nexus S.

Comment: Google's own mobile search site results have the same problem.  Occasionally you can't select things in the Options dropdown next to each link as it selects the next search result behind/near it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird one.

So, there **is** a click handler on the indicator number, and on the entire "box" holding the drop down arrow.

Android is just really finicky about whether it detects a hit to them.  I've been able to get a click to it registered to the Ask link despite my finger literally not *obscuring* (let alone touching) the Ask link.

This appears to be an Android only bug, which doesn't manifest on the iPhone or any Windows Phone.  It appears to be somewhat random, and influenced by the hardware used.  It happens quite frequently on my Nexus S, but somewhat less on other developer's phones (of different makes).  This observation is supported by your report of it not happening on Meta.SO, as the styling and code is **exactly the same** on all mobile views (at time of writing at least); there shouldn't be any functional difference between them.

Giving that the targets here are already bigger than the link that is "out competing" them, I don't really know what to do about it.  Lacking a good way to fix this, I'm forced to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) it.

Comment: This is the related bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721. It's ridiculously annoying, and I haven't been able to find a workaround for our site, either.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Kevin