# Top-right down arrow doesn't work in mobile, on questions

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, ios

This seems to be a new problem introduced in the past week or two, and is not isolated to StackOverflow but I also experience it on dba.stackexchange.

In the mobile version of the site, on an iPhone (iOS 5.0.1), the top-right down-arrow is a no-op, but only when I've navigated to an individual question. The drop-down opens up the nav just fine if I'm on the home page or the Questions tab, just not on a question. Here is a screen shot to show what I'm talking about. If I load stackoverflow.com, I can use the down-arrow... it pops open the nav with links to my profile and recent comments etc. If I click on the first question, though, the down-arrow does not function on that page.

[image]

This is not a major show-stopper by any means, and there are several workarounds. So I'm not posting here to get answers for how to make my experience better while accepting this functionality gap, I'm more hoping it's a simple fix that the devs can implement (or at least explain).

Comment: Works on my IPod in Safari

Comment: [Works on _my machine_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html) (Android Froyo)

Comment: Similar, but different: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100715/tap-on-dropdown-indicator-in-mobile-theme-doesnt-get-registered

Comment: @Manish I suspect, like the Android problem I linked to, this may be platform-specific. It may even be iOS-version specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior persisted for several days, but as of this afternoon it is working correctly. I suspect an update to the mobile site has been published, and this issue may have been fixed intentionally or as a side effect of another fix. Anyway, happy to report that the issue has fixed itself.

Comment: So was that script the answer to your deleted question?  Or did you get too many downvotes on your question? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey both. Thank you. I did get one up-vote, and I only posted the question because Yoda's comment got 3 up-votes. Anyway thanks again, I have made the problem children stand out. :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should know better than to suggest anything that would reduce activity, even if that activity leads to rage-quitting, blowing one's own brains out, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is obsoleted by the new top bar.